# How to implement keyword search in a website using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have created a website which has a search text box and i want to write a java script which can perform "search by keyword" operation:please find my html code below:Please find the screenshot attached.[image]

my html code:

```
<div class="four columns">
                    <h4>Search Podcasts</h4>
                    <a href="http://127.0.0.1:4567/podcasts/categories">Search by Category</a><br><br>
                    <a href='#' onClick='showDiv();'>Search by Keyword</a> </br></br>


                    <input type="text" name="s" id="searchtext" size="15" value="Search"  style="visibility:hidden"

                            onfocus="if (this.value==this.defaultValue)
                                this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Search'}">
    </div>
```

Comment: A search engine made in Javascript in the client? I don't think it is a good ideia.

Comment: You can you typeahead plugin from Twitter and pass the local array of keywords to do search on client side.

Comment: Whenever i enter a keyword in the search box,it should search the same page in the recent podcast container

Comment: While I like the idea of using typeahead there is also jquery and you can even make AJAX requests out to, say, NodeJS (which can search your DB and return results) if you're looking to keep it very javascript.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion,but how do implement it?